# How do I add a click handler to the GWT ButtonCell?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, click, gwt2

I created a [ButtonCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html) and a [Column](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html) for it:

```
ButtonCell previewButton = new ButtonCell();
Column<Auction,String> preview = new Column<Auction,String>(previewButton) {
  public String getValue(Auction object) {
    return "Preview";
  }
};
```

How do I now add a click handler (e.g. [ClickHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ClickHandler.html)) for this [ButtonCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Cell Sampler](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) example includes use of clickable ButtonCells. Clicks on ButtonCells are handled by setting the [FieldUpdater](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/FieldUpdater.html) for the Column:

```
preview.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Auction, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, Auction object, String value) {
    // The user clicked on the button for the passed auction.
  }
});
```

Comment: but how to place regular button in cell table??

Comment: redrawButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        contactList.redraw();
      }
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Prevent mouse events  for table cell
 CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Auction > manager = DefaultSelectionEventManager.createBlacklistManager(4);//column number
 cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, manager);

 new Column<Auction , String>(new ButtonCell()){

    @Override
    public String getValue(Auction object) {
        return "Preview";
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Cell.Context context, Element elem, Auction object, NativeEvent event) {
        event.preventDefault();

       //TODO implement event handling 
    }
}
```